# PHP - Как вывести с группировкой таблицу с иерархией?

Tags: php, html

Имеется такая таблица с иерархией, как вывести её в html таблицу с группировкой?

pid - id родительской категории

level - уровень иерархии

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ваш вопрос нуждается в указании конкретики. Что Вам именно непонятно: как выводить информацию с помощью php, как из php выполнять запросы к БД, как группировать данные в SQL или что-нибудь другое? Более того Вы не указали как именно уровень иерархии должен повлиять на выводимую информацию.

Comment: Мне непонятно как написать функцию вывода в php, чтобы данные отобразились в html в виде таблицы с группировкой по иерархии. Я подразумеваю что надо в цикле вставлять табличные тэги.